# How to make two midnight commander like layout in BS5 / Angular 13

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I'd like to achieve the following layout for my component:

```
|-----------|
-------------
|     |     |
|     |     |
|     |     |
|     |     |
-------------
```

Toolbox with buttons on the top and two fixed sized panels with borders and scrolls bottom left and right.

Should I do some research in flex tools, or simple stylesheet would solve my case?

Answer (score 0):

For a visual builder you could use http://shoelace.io/ for the layout and other bootstrap elements for the toolbar https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/b5/angular/navigation/navbar/

This code can be pasted to `shoelace`.

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]